# How To get Records between two dates Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to search the records between two dates , but this code is not working .

```
protected void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string ToDate = txtDateTo.Text;
    string DateFrom = txtDateFrom.Text;
    dt = NewLeadClass.GetReport(ToDate, DateFrom);
}    


public static DataTable GetReport(string ToDate,string FromDate)
{
 SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[]
 {
           new SqlParameter("@ToDate", ToDate),
           new SqlParameter("@FromDate",FromDate)   
       };
 DataSet ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(Utility.GetConString(), CommandType.Text, "Select * from EmpDailyReport where RecordDate <= @ToDate and RecordDate>= @FromDate",param);
    return ds.Tables[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CHANGE YOUR QUERY TO :

```
 DataSet ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(Utility.GetConString(), CommandType.Text, "Select * from EmpDailyReport where RecordDate BETWEEN  @FromDate  and @ToDate 

   changesdone here :   "where RecordDate BETWEEN  @FromDate  and @ToDate "
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are comparing two strings and not "dates",  so try to parse your dates as a date or datetime objects and retry.

Ps: in your where clause you can use something like this instead :

`where RecordDate between FromDate and ToDate`